# How to conveniently define a list of named integer constants?

Tags: python, dictionary, global-variables, config, constants

I want to define constants, e.g. `A = 10; B = 20`, with these properties:

1. 'Normal' access: e.g. `A.value + B.value == 30` (or even `A + B == 30`)
2. Allow duplicate values: e.g. `A = 10; B = 10`
3. Associated string for each variable: e.g. `A.name == "A"`
4. Listing: e.g. `[v.name for v in CONSTANTS]`
5. IDE support: auto-complete names, re-factorizations, etc.
6. Adding a new constant requires **one change**
7. Importable: e.g. `from config import CONSTANTS`

In the end, the property #6 is the problem. Something like

```
A = 10
B = 20

A_NAME = "A"
B_NAME = "B"

CONSTANTS = { A_NAME: A, B_NAME: B }
```

would basically be the solution. But I would like to avoid this verbose code (if possible).

---

This attempt comes very close:

```
import enum

class CONSTANTS(enum.IntEnum):
    A = 10
    B = 20

assert CONSTANTS.A + CONSTANTS.B == 30
assert CONSTANTS.A.name == "A"
assert CONSTANTS.__members__.keys() == ["A", "B"]
assert CONSTANTS.__members__.values() == [10, 20]
```

but fails when two constants have the same value (property #2). One could also define a sub-class of `Enum` with a constructor taking `value`. But again, `A = 10; B = 10` would be mapped to the same instance, even though the name differs. One could now also add a name (or any other unused, but distinctive parameter to the constructor) to make this problem go away. But I would consider this approach unclean. For instance, `A = ("A", 10); B = ("B", 10); def __init__(self, _, value): ...`.

Comment: why does your proposal need to inherit from `enum`? Why can't you just define the class with properties and override the `__add__`, etc., as necessary?

Comment: But how would I access the element *name* for such a class? For `class C(): A=1; B=2`, how do I access `C.B.name` or something similar?

Comment: Bleh, crazy int subclasses. They seem all nice and convenient until they propagate somewhere unexpected and your program starts printing `CrazyInternalEnum.WEIRD_NAME` instead of `3` or a duck-typing check takes the wrong code path because it wasn't expecting an integer to have a `name` attribute.

Comment: I totally agree. Accessing the value via an attribute is totally fine for me and of course more fail-safe.

Comment: @user2357112 To eliminate possible misunderstandings. The 'crazy int subclass' thing would be something which is nice to have, but not required. For me a 'value' attribute is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the CONSTANTS dict thing less verbose by using `globals()` to copy the dict contents into global variables:

```
CONSTANTS = {"A": 10, "B": 20}
globals().update(CONSTANTS)

print(B)  # prints 20
```

Comment: Yes, but then pycharm (or other IDEs) is not aware of these variables, right?

Comment: @MichaelHoff: Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) collection?

```
from collections import namedtuple

IntConst = namedtuple('IntConst', ['name', 'value'])

A = IntConst('A',10)
B = IntConst('B',20)
```

They meet your "Normal Access" by field....

```
A.value + B.value
```

They won't complain when multiple `IntConst` have the same value...

```
A = IntConst('A',10)
B = IntConst('B',10)
```

They will give an associated string ...

```
A.name
```

They will allow listing ...

```
CONSTANTS = list()
CONSTANTS.extend([A,B])
[v.name for v in CONSTANTS]
```

Your IDE probably already has support for `namedtuple`. Adding more constants simply requires you to create an instance of the `IntConst` `namedtuple`. As for importing, you'd simply create a list of those `IntConst` values in your namespace and they'd become valid targets for the `import` statement.

The only thing they don't give that you requested is the ability to duck type an integer value out of them. Instead, you'll get a tuple containing both `IntConst` instances.

```
>>> A+B
('A', 10, 'B', 10)
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. However, I have to create the variable **and** put it in the list if I introduce a new one.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Accessing a hidden attribute is discouraged and should thus not be considered a 'clean' solution!*

The standard Enum module can be *tweaked* to provide the desired behavior.

```
import enum

class Const1(enum.Enum):
    A = 42
    B = 42

    def __init__(self, size):
        self._value_ = (self.name, size)
        self.size = size

class Const2(enum.IntEnum):
    A = 42
    B = 42

    def __init__(self, size):
        enum.IntEnum.__init__(self)
        self._value_ = (self.name, size)
```

Padding the `_value_` attribute with the name of the member, renders the [alias lookup mechanism](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/enum.py#L212) unable to find other members with the same value. The only drawback is that the `value` attribute of the produced members all refer to their internal `_value_` attribute. In fact, `value` is defined as a [`DynamicClassAttribute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.DynamicClassAttribute). Hence, without further modifications we face: `Const1.A.value == ('A', 42)`.

If desired, a property can be used to overwrite this behavior.

```
@property
def value(self):
    return self._value_[1]
```